# A Simple weather is not working when it's live on the internet

Tags: javascript

I built a simple weather app. It's working on my local computer. However, when I push my code on Github and put it live on the internet with Github's free domain, it has two different results.

https://rainey8507.github.io/weather/

[it's just working on my local computer but not working when I put my code live on Github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWwYM.jpg)

Comment: How do you even get the location of the user?

Answer (score 0):

The page is being loaded over HTTPS, but the request to the OpenWeatherMap API is using HTTP. To fix this all you have to do is change the URL to start with `https://`

Answer (score 0):

```js
"use strict"

const url = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Oklahoma&appid=8f2718bde4ff4634f3ca8f1c0e831789"

$.ajax ({
    url: url,
     headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
    success:function (result){
        console.log(result);
        console.log(result.name);
        // output the location
        $("#location").text(result.name);

        // Display the temperature
        /*let F = Math.round(result.main.temp * (9/5) - 459.67);
        let displayTemp = `Temperature: ${F}&#176;F`;*/
        let F = Math.round(result.main.temp * (9/5) - 459.67);
        let Fahrenheit = F.toString();
        $("#temperature").text(Fahrenheit);

        let windSpeed = Math.round(result.wind.speed / .44704);
        let wind = windSpeed.toString();
        $("#wind").text(wind);

        $("#sky").text(result.weather[0].description);
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Replace your weather/weather.js file with the snippet below: